# Ubuntu 14.10 doesn't detect my SSD drive

Tags: ssd, 14.10

I have problem with my brand new SSD drive. Ubuntu installer doesn't detect it. Syslog says

```
[    6.872065] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf7a22000 port 0xf7a22100 irq 58
[    7.189114] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    7.267205] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:09:00:00:00:b0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[    7.273640] ata1.00: ATA-9: INTEL SSDSC2BW120A4, DC32, max UDMA/133
[    7.273645] ata1.00: 234441648 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    7.339149] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:09:00:00:00:b0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[    7.360004] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    7.360540] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 234441648 512-byte logical blocks: (120 GB/111 GiB)
[    7.360645] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    7.360649] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    7.360682] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    7.361162]  sda: unknown partition table
[    7.361406] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[   11.187644] ata1: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4090800 action 0xe frozen
[   11.187649] ata1: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[   11.187652] ata1: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg 10B8B DevExch }
[   11.187656] ata1: hard resetting link
[   11.910482] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[   16.907658] ata1: hard resetting link
[   17.227486] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[   17.227494] ata1: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[   22.224753] ata1: hard resetting link
[   22.544563] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[   22.544572] ata1.00: disabled
[   22.544582] ata1: EH complete
[   22.544594] ata1.00: detaching (SCSI 0:0:0:0)
[   22.545007] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[   22.545045] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[   22.545048] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   22.545051] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[   22.545060] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] START_STOP FAILED
[   22.545062] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[   22.545064] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

It looks like some kind of hardware problem, but I don't think so. Disk is brand new. Can somebody help me?
Best regards
Juszczyk Paweł

Answer (score 0):

This may be one of the reasons:

```
[    7.361162]  sda: unknown partition table
```

However, I find these warnings more worrying:

```
[   11.187652] ata1: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg 10B8B DevExch }
[   11.187656] ata1: hard resetting link
[   11.910482] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[   16.907658] ata1: hard resetting link
[   17.227486] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[   17.227494] ata1: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[   22.224753] ata1: hard resetting link
[   22.544563] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[   22.544572] ata1.00: disabled
```

It looks like the communication between the SSD and the controller isn't going well. Could this be a cable issue? Or maybe switch the disk to another SATA port.